# np.where comparison between 2 arrays

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have 4 numpy arrays as:

```
mat_row.shape, mat_col.shape
# ((3000, 2000), (3000, 2000))

nearest_neighb_x.shape, nearest_neighb_y.shape
# (2040,) (2040,)
```

The idea is to perform a lookup for unique values of `nearest_neighb_x` and `nearest_neighb_y` existing in `mat_col` and `mat_row` with condition checks (xc and yc should lie within a specific range):

Currently, I am using two `for` loops for this (inefficient and slow):

```
x1, x2 = 822, 1414
y1, y2 = 760, 2516

# Python3 list to contain candidate (xc, yc) cam/image space pxs on object-
cand_x = []
cand_y = []

for xp in np.unique(nearest_neighb_x):
    for yp in np.unique(nearest_neighb_y):
        # Get (x, y) coord in cam/image space-
        yc = np.where(mat_row == yp)[0][0]
        xc = np.where(mat_col == xp)[1][0]

        if (xc >= (x1 + 45)) & (xc <= (x2 - 45)):
            cand_x.append(xc)

        if (yc >= (y1 + 45)) & (yc <= (y2 - 45)):
            cand_y.append(yc)

cand_x = np.array(cand_x)
cand_y = np.array(cand_y)
```

Is there an efficient implementation for this by avoiding the `for` loops?

Comment: Does your current code work as intended? Would it not be possible to append `xc` and not `yc` such that `cand_x` and `cand_y` may not be the same length?

Comment: Also, what are the `dtype`s of your arrays?

Comment: What are `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, and `y2`?

Comment: @jared dtypes are: mat_row and mat_col = dtype('float32'). Same for nearest_neighb_x and nearest_neighb_y. cand_x and cand_y are dtype('int64')

Comment: It's bad practice to perform an equality comparison with floating-point numbers, due to floating-point precision.